# Почему не присваивается значение к указателю?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int* a = new int;
*a = 4;  //ошибка
int main()
  {
   system("pause");
  }
```

Но если занести присвоение *a = 4 в функцию,то нет ошибки,почему?

Comment: потому что вызов оператора вы пишете не в функции

Comment: не знал,а почему нельзя присваивать не в функции?

Comment: В С / С++ вне функций можно только что-то объявлять или определять, но не исполнять произвольные выражения, так как поток управления вне функций не гуляет.

Comment: Вызов функции — это выражение, которое указывает процессору прервать выполнение текущей функции и приступить к выполнению другой функции. 
Если вы выполняете вызов функции (оператора) вне функции, то выше указанное правило нарушается.... Выполнение начинается в главной функции  main, а не до нее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа начинается с выполнения `main`, так ведь? Так **когда** должно выполняться ваше присваивание?

Но вы можете выполнять до `main` *инициализацию* объявленных глобальных переменных, этот код (если таковой подразумевается конструктором) будет выполнен.

В вашем случае достаточно превратить присвоение в инициализацию - легким движением руки:

```
int * a = new int(4);
```